# Special characters encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

My project setup is based on Angular generated from CLI and I'm facing issues with displaying local german characters.

My `meta` in `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

My editor VS Code is set to save files in `UTF-8`:

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.detectIndentation": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": false,
  "files.encoding": "utf8",

  },
"[typescript]": {
  "files.encoding": "utf8",
},
"files.encoding": "utf8",
```

My document request headers:

```
GET /home?schedule=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:4200/home?schedule=2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: utilityType=HEAT
```

And respective response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 898
ETag: W/"382-xsHtQLNHNB+FVVszGe2IsoXNXEI"
Date: Fri, 31 Aug 2018 09:05:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

I'm using Google Fonts Open Sans with `latin-extended` set:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any outputting results still looks like below:

[image]

I'm running out of ideas what else may affect this?

Comment: First you need to look at the bytes of your response, not at rendered output., Save to file and open in an editor that can show you actual bytes. This will let you narrow down the problem to either client or server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as already mentioned by @n.m. , issue was that localisation files were produced by external translation team, which saved all text feeds as ANSI, not as UTF-8 encoding. Converting files from ANSI to UTF resolved issue.